# Creating a nested model from within the parent create method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a landlord class and it has N addresses.
Landlord accepts nested attributes for addresses
I have  a form which is used to create the landlord in that form is a sub-form for creating an address.

The address requires a landlord_id to be valid and therefore save.

As I am creating the landlord how do I create the address without having to save the landlord twice in the create method call in the landlord controller?

landlord_controller.rb#create

```
def create      
     #check if a landlord of the same name already exists and load that instead
     @landlord = Landlord.where(:name => params[:landlord][:name], \
       :city_id => params[:landlord][:city_id], \
       :province_id => params[:landlord][:province_id]). 
     first_or_create

 if @landlord.save 

   flash[:success] =  #"Thank you for submitting a Landlord " 
   #@landlord.addresses.build ....
   #@landlord.save
   redirect_to @landlord
 else
    render :new     
 end
end
```

landlord/new.html.erb # form

```
<%= form_for @landlord do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :address do  |address_form| %>

     <%= address_form.label :number %>
     <%= address_form.text_field :number %>

     <%= address_form.label :street %>
     <%= address_form.text_field :street %>

     <%= address_form.label "#{:unit}# / Apt #" %>
     <%= address_form.text_field :unit %>

     <%= address_form.label :postal %>
     <%= address_form.text_field :postal %>

 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Actually, second `@landlord.save` saves addresses. If you don't want to do this you can save each `address` separately.

Comment: In your experience which method is more advantageous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, use `find_or_initialize_by(...)` instead of `where(...).first_or_create` (alternatively, you can keep the same `where` pattern and use `first_or_initialize`).  Then use `assign_attributes` to add the addresses, and finally try to `save`.  And as @CodeGroover recommends, you can refactor this somewhat:

```
other_params = params[:landlord].slice!(:name, :city_id, :province_id)
@landlord = Landlord.find_or_initialize_by(params[:landlord])

@landlord.assign_attributes(other_params)

if @landlord.save
  ...
```

Comment: mini-refactoring: Landlord.find_or_initialize_by(params[:landlord])

Comment: then maybe params[:landlord].except(:addresses)

Comment: @CodeGroover: Sort of, except you want to limit it to the search criteria. I would compromise using `slice`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Added the permit calls into it and works like a charm.